# Pythonsave data to folder

Tags: python

I'm new to python, I'm using this code to download images and then it's being saved to the same directory as the python file. 
How can I save them to another folder?

```
def requesthandle( link, name ):
    global THREAD_COUNTER
    THREAD_COUNTER += 1
    try:
        r = requests.get( link, stream=True )
        if r.status_code == 200:
            r.raw.decode_content = True
           **Saving images**
            f = open( name, "wb" )
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
            f.close()
            print ("[*] Downloaded Image: %s" % name)
    except Exception as error:
        print ("[~] Error Occured with %s : %s" % (name, error))
    THREAD_COUNTER -= 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to check if the directory is exist or not, if not let's create one

And also u need to change where the files will be saved

Here is an exemple

```
import os

def requesthandle( link, name ):
    global THREAD_COUNTER
    THREAD_COUNTER += 1

    if not os.path.exists('/downloads'): #check if the folder is exist 
        os.makedir('/downloads') # if not let create one xD
    try:
        r = requests.get( link, stream=True )
        if r.status_code == 200:
            r.raw.decode_content = True
            f = open( "/downloads/"+str(name) , "wb" ) # And here change where the file will be saved xD
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
            f.close()
            print ("[*] Downloaded Image: %s" % name)
    except Exception as error:
        print ("[~] Error Occured with %s : %s" % (name, error))
    THREAD_COUNTER -= 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm getting this error:  File "scraper.py", line 32, in requesthandle
    os.mkdir('/Abstracts')
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/Abstracts'

Comment: @KerbyJean can u show me all your code because here is just 19 line

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to `open` is the path to the file; if only the name is provided, the current directory is used.

So you just need to prepend the path to the directory you want (there are os.path functions to help with this) to the name of the file.

Comment: I'm new to all this, would you mind showing some code please?